# How to add safeArea in React Native for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing an app with react native and testing it with my android emulator.The `SafeAreaView` component in React Native is currently applicable only to ios devices with ios version 11 or later.

Did someone know about anything to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SafeAreaView for IOS and use a padding for Android

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      //Rest of your app
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#A6A9BC',
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 25 : 0
},
});
```